# How do you "preselect" a file in the NSOpenPanel dialog

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

Does anyone know how to **preselect** a file in the `NSOpenPanel` dialog?

This has been asked several times before, but none of those questions were answered with a working solution. Setting nameFieldStringValue has no effect as the open dialog does not have a textfield for the user to type in a name. Setting the directoryURL only sets the current directory in the dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
NSOpenPanel *op=[NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[op setDirectoryURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/Home/Desktop/yourfile.sh/"]];
[op runModal];
```

Comment: As I indicated in my question, setting the directoryURL only makes the dialog show that directory. It does not actually select the file.

Comment: I just ran a test where I hard coded the path and you are correct. It does select the filename. That must mean that in my regular logic I am not properly building the path. Thank-you for the confirmation.

Comment: It turns out that my problem was using `[panel setDirectoryURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]];` instead of `[panel setDirectoryURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path]];`

Comment: Note that this does *not* work on 10.6, the first OS X version for which this API is available; instead it treats the file if it were an empty directory.  (It works fine on 10.7 and 10.8, and I imagine on 10.9 though I haven't tested it.)

Comment: Interesting that there is an internal difference between URLWithString and fileURLWithPath which produce identical output in NSLog.