# NSOpenPanel preselect multiple files

Tags: objective-c, nsopenpanel

While there are [quite a few questions about how to preselect a file on NSOpenPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903904/how-do-you-preselect-a-file-in-the-nsopenpanel-dialog), they set `openPanel.directoryURL` to the path of the target file. However `NSOpenPanel` can allow for multiple files to be selected via the `openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection` property. Is there a way to preselect multiple files?

The intuitive way would be to set `openPanel.urls` but that is read-only.